# ListTile within a Card causing RenderBox was not laid

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, card, renderbox, listtile

I am trying to put ListTile within a Card but I am getting a renderbox error

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#c872a relayoutBoundary=up7
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Card
lib/…/task/make_offer.dart:100


ListView(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16.0,
            vertical: 10.0,
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: _offerController,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            // textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
            // maxLength: 40,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: '5-9999',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money_rounded),
              labelText: 'Your Offer',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter
            ],
            onChanged: (offerAmount) => _offerAmount = offerAmount as int,
          ),
        ),
        Card(
            child: ListTile(
                leading: Text('Fee'),
                trailing: Text(_offerController.toString())))
      ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming from `ListTile`'s `trailing`, you can wrap `Text` with `SizedBox(width:x)`. Issue occurs on large text.

```dart
  Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Text('Fee'),
              trailing: SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                child: Text(
                  "_offerController.toString()xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxsd",
                     /// you can add others property here
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Also, you can create custom ListTile while its default behavior. Here is a [sample](https://gist.github.com/yeasin50/e079c0e90179393ad27de7c0be132489)

Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Interesting as the text is only max 5 digits long but that does seem to fix it

Comment: It may be different from my device. I'm using `chrome`, only when test is long enough it creates the issue, that's why I've used, for 5 digits, I can't find any issue on my side, maybe just because of screen resolution.

Comment: I think the issue now after looking at it is using the Row within the leading